# Applying for Graduate School after dropping out of my first degree

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

A decade ago, I enrolled in a STEM undergraduate degree because the part of the world I am from, engineers and doctors are considered as the only respectable professions and social sciences are a big no no. I did well in my first year but it was the second year when I started despising every single minute of my time in school. It got to the point where it impacted my mental health and I withdrew from the university completely.

A few years later, I restarted my academic journey, but this time in the social sciences, as I always wanted to do. I have received multiple awards and scholarships for academic achievement and am one of the top performing students of my batch.

I am now applying for graduate school in the same field in which I'm currently studying. My only concern is that my previous 'drop-out' will have a negative impact on my application.

Comment: Unlikely that it will have any impact at all. People change. People grow. Moreover your recent record is weighted much more heavily than the past for most purposes. And, there is little you can do in any case. The past is what it is.

Comment: What is your question?